# How to remove red color text in the excel cell with PHPExcell?

Tags: php, phpexcel

There is a cell with black and red color words. I need to remove red color words with`phpExcell`. How can i do this ?

Comment: what did you do to make them red in phpExcell?

Comment: I didn't create excel file using phpexcel. I have excell file created with MSEXcell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cell combines both read and black text, then it contains a rich text value, and a call to getValue() will return a RichText object. If you simply want the text, cast that to a string, and the magic __toString() method for the RichText object will return the data as a plain string value. You can then set that value back to the cell.

If you need to eliminate the Red words, then you'll need to parse the different runs of text in the RichText object, identifying which runs have a red style setting, and concatenating those that don't into a plain PHP string